GTK4 Build Issues
I have hit a wall trying to install GTK4. I have followed both alternative instructions on the GTK site. I am on Windows 11 and using Visual Studio 2022 Community. When I run gvsbuild build gtk4, I receive numerous errors as follows:
PS C:\Users\Robert Petrowsky\source\repos> gvsbuild build gtk4
Build type is Configuration.debug_optimized
Cleaning up the build environment
Checking msys tool
Using C:\msys64 for msys installation
Checking Msvc tool

Visual Studio installation(s) found:
    Visual Studio Community 2022 @ C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools

Using Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
Downloading packages
Building project ninja (1.11.1)
Building project meson (1.4.0)
(tar) Exporting pkgconf
Building project pkgconf (2.2.0)
[1/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_argvsplit.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_argvsplit.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_argvsplit.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_argvsplit.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/argvsplit.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[2/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_audit.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_audit.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_audit.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_audit.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/audit.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[3/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_bsdstubs.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_bsdstubs.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_bsdstubs.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_bsdstubs.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/bsdstubs.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[4/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_cache.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_cache.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_cache.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_cache.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/cache.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[5/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_client.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_client.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_client.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_client.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/client.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[6/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_dependency.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_dependency.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_dependency.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_dependency.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/dependency.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[7/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_fileio.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_fileio.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_fileio.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_fileio.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/fileio.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[8/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_fragment.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_fragment.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_fragment.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_fragment.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/fragment.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[9/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_parser.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_parser.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_parser.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_parser.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/parser.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[10/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_path.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_path.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_path.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_path.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/path.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[11/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_personality.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_personality.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_personality.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_personality.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/personality.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[12/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_pkg.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_pkg.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_pkg.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_pkg.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/pkg.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[13/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_queue.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_queue.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_queue.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_queue.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/queue.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
[14/21] Compiling C object pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_tuple.c.obj
FAILED: pkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_tuple.c.obj
"cl" "-Ipkgconf-5.dll.p" "-I." "-I.." "/MD" "/nologo" "/showIncludes" "/utf-8" "/W2" "/O2" "/Zi" "-D_BSD_SOURCE" "-D_DEFAULT_SOURCE" "-DLIBPKGCONF_EXPORT" "-DPKGCONFIG_IS_NOT_STATIC" "/Fdpkgconf-5.dll.p\libpkgconf_tuple.c.pdb" /Fopkgconf-5.dll.p/libpkgconf_tuple.c.obj "/c" ../libpkgconf/tuple.c
CreateProcess failed: The system cannot find the file specified.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gvsbuild\utils\builder.py", line 527, in build
    if self.__build_one(p):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gvsbuild\utils\builder.py", line 663, in __build_one
    skip_deps = proj.build()
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gvsbuild\projects\pkgconf.py", line 37, in build
    Meson.build(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gvsbuild\utils\base_builders.py", line 56, in build
    self.builder.exec_ninja(params="install", working_dir=ninja_build)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gvsbuild\utils\builder.py", line 985, in exec_ninja
    self.__execute(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gvsbuild\utils\builder.py", line 1041, in __execute
    subprocess.check_call(args, cwd=working_dir, env=env, shell=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py", line 413, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'ninja install' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Error: pkgconf build failed

I have updated Visual Studio and installed what appear to be all relevant C++ compilers. I have gone through every explanation I can find online and can't seem to make any progress.
As far as I can tell, I have a partial installation of GTK4. When I import gtk.gtkh, I don't get any errors, other than a pointer error that seems to indicate that the library is incomplete.
I have followed all instructions for building GTK4 as listed on the gtk.org site. I tried both the MSYS2 and the gvsbuild options. Neither seem to install a complete package. I have primarily relied on the gvsbuild option as it indicates it is appropriate for Visual Studio.
Everything works perfect until I execute gvsbuild build GTK4. Then I receive the errors indicated above.
I have tried this in command prompt, power shell, and the Visual Studio terminal. None work.

Bump. If anyone has some advice, I would appreciate it. What else can I post to help answer the question?
